# Write to the input of process strings received by socket

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sockets, ssl

I have an application on the **Windows** platform that receives remote commands from applications running on the **Linux** platform.

The **Linux** applications are experiencing difficulties accessing directories or files that contain accented characters, they send the command to access such files/directories and the return is always:  "directory/file not found".

I think the two applications are with different **code page**, I venture to say this because I previously had problems in linux applications, the directories and files with accented words came with strange symbols in `std::cout`, and after I added `SetConsoleOutputCP (CP_UTF8)` in the windows application the problem was solved, and finally the paths containing accents were readable, does this mean that the linux application has code page 65001? Anyway, the problem when sending strings containing the path to the directories/files still persists, whenever the linux application tries to access paths containing accented words it fails.

I'll try to show how the two applications communicate.

**Windows Side:**

In short, this is the part where the client receives the message from the linux application, and then writes in the process what was received. In this part when writing paths containing accented characters the application returns in the output that is not possible to find them.

```
BYTE buffer[4096];
DWORD BytesWritten;

int ret = SSL_read(stI->ssl, (char*)buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if (ret <= 0)
    break;

if(!WriteFile(stI->hStdIn, buffer, ret, &BytesWritten, NULL))
    break;
```

And then it reads the output of the process and sends the content to the Linux application.

```
BYTE buffer[4096];
DWORD BytesAvailable, BytesRead;

if (!ReadFile(stI->hStdOut, buffer, min(sizeof(buffer), BytesAvailable), &BytesRead, NULL))
  break;

ret = SSL_write(stI->ssl, (char*)buffer, BytesAvailable);
if (ret <= 0)
  break;
```

**Linux Side:**

This part is very basic, the application reads a user input and then sends it to the windows application.

```
std::string inputBuffer;
ZH->console_input(inputBuffer, 33); // This function only controls the input and output of data with termios.

inputBuffer+='\n' // To simulate an enter in windows application

// Sends the typed path to the Windows application
SSL_write(session_data.ssl, inputBuffer.c_str(), strlen(inputBuffer.c_str()))
```

The part of receiving the data is basically the same as the windows application, it receives the data in a char variable and then print on the screen with `std::cout`.
The only difference is that the socket is set to NONBLOCK and I use the select function.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you do know of the [`std::string::length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i know, are you talking about ssl write? is better use inputBuffer.length()?

Comment: As for your problem, can you please elaborate? What do you send from the Linux program to the Windows program? What does the Windows program receive? What is written to the file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the application is like a ssh for windows. Only sends commands, and receives the output of the windows shell. But, having this small character-conflict problem between applications with accented words.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use proper unicode encodings. Windows tends to use UTF-16 (uses 2 bytes to represent a character), Linux on the other hand uses UTF-8. This is typically uses a single byte per character for ASCII and escapes non ascii characters (\uxxxx where x represents a hex digit). If you do a proper conversion from Windows UTF-16 to UTF-8, things should work correctly.

C++11 and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html) do provide some Unicode support, but for gold standard support, take a look at [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Sockets however just transmit bytes so they have nothing to do with Unicode conversions.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can do the conversions? In which application should I do? I can use boost in this application. I've tried all kinds of conversion, I've been doing this all night.